# (Why) does enumitem cause poor hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation, enumitem

I have noticed some cases of poor hyphenation in my document.  Specifically, LaTeX is breaking hyphenated words like "large-scale" somewhere *other* than the hyphen.  (I thought that this was something that LaTeX famously refuses to do!)

So far I've noticed the problem only in inline lists produced with the `enumitem` package.  Perhaps this is just a coincidence, but I never see the problem in similarly worded text that doesn't use inline lists.  Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
% This paragraph is hyphenated correctly
Foo bar f:
(i)~Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.

% This paragraph is hyphenated poorly
Foo bar f:
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the above code, showing a strange "large-s-cale" linebreak]

What's going on here?  Is it `enumitem` that is at fault?  Regardless, is there any way of fixing it?  I tried changing `large-scale` to `\mbox{large}-\mbox{scale}` but LaTeX refuses to break the line at the hyphen.  (In any case, I would prefer a global solution rather than one that requires me to manually locate and fix every mishyphenated word.)

Comment: Interesting question. I can reproduce this problem when compiling the above with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`, but not with `lualatex`. (That is, LuaTeX, unlike XeTeX and pdfTeX, seems to hyphenate correctly, and not have this problem… in a way it's a shame, as I was hoping LuaTeX callbacks may be useful for peeking into the internal data-structures and seeing what's going on.)

Comment: Inline enumerations are hard to read and hard to recognize. I wouldn't use them at all, regardless whether done with `enumitem` or any other package or the manual way

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, even Knuth uses them in _The TeXbook_: in `texbook.tex` there are 32 instances of `(1)~` (inline enumerations done manually). (Corresponding to pages 10, 27, 34, 39, 60, 80, 81, …, 403, 454 of _The TeXbook_.) (I doubt he uses them in TAOCP though, because there equations have labels, and so using something like “(1)” in a paragraph can be misleading as it usually means a reference to Equation 1.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes, but it still does not look nice ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is due to the fact that `enumerate*` boxes the contents and then does `\unhbox`. No wonder it doesn't happen with XeLaTeX (with nonlegacy fonts) and LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% This paragraph is hyphenated correctly
Foo bar f:
(i)~Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.

% This paragraph is hyphenated poorly
Foo bar f:
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.
\end{enumerate*}

% This paragraph is hyphenated poorly
\setbox0=\hbox{Foo bar f:
(i)~Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.}
\leavevmode\unhbox0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Boxing text loses the reference to the current language and mysterious things can happen. Use `mode=unboxed`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% This paragraph is hyphenated correctly
Foo bar f:
(i)~Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.

% This paragraph is hyphenated poorly
Foo bar f:
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*),mode=unboxed]
\item Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar foo bar foo bar large-scale foo bar foo bar.
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}supercalifragilistic-expialidocious test}

\vfill\eject

\setbox0=\hbox{supercalifragilistic-expialidocious}
\parbox{0pt}{\hskip0pt\unhbox0\relax\space test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!!! +1 for your amazing answer.

Comment: Thanks, am not the OP, but natural follow-up questions: Why does `\unhbox` result in these poor hyphenations? Why does enumitem do things this way? Is there anything better about `mode=boxed`, as reason why `mode=unboxed` is not the default (or even only) option?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The `boxed` mode allows for `itemjoin*`. Boxing text and unboxing it has been a weak point of TeX since the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, the `itemjoin*` explains the need for `boxed` (though I guess it may still make sense to use `unboxed` by default, and print the warning asking to use `boxed` when `itemjoin*` is requested). Separately, I've been trying to reproduce the `\setbox0=\hbox … \unhbox0` example in plain TeX (to understand it better), but not quite able to get the line-break after the `s`: is there some trick that happens in LaTeX that I'm missing?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I noticed the same, too. I think it's something related to babel.

Comment: I especially like how TeX threw in a hyphen after `tic-` to make it `tic--` and thus give an en dash in the right-hand output.